# No of Partitions created in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have created a table in Cassandra with one partition key (i.e one primary key) and have insert about 50K records in it where 35K are unique records.

According to the rule (Please correct me if I am wrong), the no of partitions in Cassandra should be equal to the unique records in the table (i.e no of partitions = unique record in primary key ).

But while I did the node tool -

./nodetool tablestats -H keyspace.tablename

it gives me:-

```
    Number of keys (estimate partitions key): 7500
```

i.e much less than the no of unique records in mine table.

So please can anyone explain this scenario.

Comment: Do you have only 1 node? Did you flush? What version?

Answer (score 5):

tablestats only gives you relative size of the number of keys, not the exact size. 
If you want to know total unique rows, run `select count(partition_key_col) from tableName`. 
It is possible that you get query timeout when executing the query, set  `cqlsh request-timeout` before executing the query.

Answer (score 4):

As you described you have 35k unique records in your tables.
Unique record in Cassandra is (partition key(PK) + clustering columns(CC)).
correcting your statement here. Number of Partitions = Unique Partition Keys (Not the Primary Key(PK+CC).)
So It might be the case that for the same partition key, you might have more than 1 rows based on your clustering columns.

And that is the reason you have around 7.5k unique partitions and overall it will have unique 35k records.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablestats.html#toolsTablestats__example

Here if you read the significance of **Number of keys (estimate)**, It says the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The tablestats are refreshed on flush. If you manually run a nodetool flush you should see an accurate number.